# LaTeX font error: I can't find file `pzdr'

Tags: fonts, errors

I was to use the package `pifont` to use `\ding{52}` in my document.
However, when I use `\usepackage{pifont}`, I get the below error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2008basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2008basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm pzdr
/usr/local/texlive/2008basic/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for pzdr.
/usr/local/texlive/2008basic/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pzdr
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (Web2C 7.5.7)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf pzdr
! I can't find file `pzdr'.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pzdr

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pzdr

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: pzdr.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pzdr' failed to make pzdr.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font U/pzd/m/n/10=pzdr at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
extract@font ...ont font@name external@font relax 
                                                  font@name relax csname f@e...

define@newfont ...ong@fontshape else extract@font 
                                                  fi endgroup 
pickup@font ...ifx font@name relax define@newfont 
                                                  fi 
selectfont  ...ape /f@size endcsname }pickup@font 
                                                  font@name size@update enc@...
l.62 {\Pifont{pzd}
                  }
```

I am not sure why I get this error. I can see the pifont.sty is present in the directory : `/usr/local/texlive/2008basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985361/latex-font-error?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's after the 'pzdr.tfm' font file. Can you try `locate pzdr.tfm` (if you're on a unix-like system) to locate it?

For me, it appears in the following places:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/zapfding/pzdr.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/cspsfonts-adobe/zapfding/rpzdr.tfm
```

Hence I think you have to install the `zapfding` package first (`sudo tlmgr install zapfding`).

Comment: locate pzdr.tfm returns nothing.
When I try to install zapfding, I get the below error for the mirrors:
tlmgr: installation location http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/2008
unusable location http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/2008/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb, could not load any packages
Cannot load TeX Live database from http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/2008 at /usr/texbin/tlmgr line 2221.

Comment: How to you usually install latex packages? Just do that. (Could you try `tlmgr update --list`?)

Comment: Thanks. I got all the missing files (there were a couple of them missing) from http://tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/fonts/ and now it works fine.

Comment: Any reason why you are still using TL 2008?

Comment: Addendum in 2019: if you don’t have the file installed at all, you’d want to check `apt-file search pzdr.tfm` on a Debian-based system, or `tlmgr info` if it’s a local installation, or do an online search of your distro's repo and CTAN.

Answer (score 27):

In Ubuntu precise 12.04, you should install texlive-fonts-recommended.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Comment: In fedora, I used: `yum install texlive-texmf-fonts`, which solved the issue for me.

Comment: This also worked in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: On CentOS, I solved it with: `yum install texlive-collection-latexrecommended` (the missing file for me was ecrm1095)

Comment: This works also for linux mint. And I guess will work for any Ubuntu-based system, unless they decide to change the packages.

Comment: works for ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

under linux mint I used

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

and it is now ok!

Answer (score 1):

Tested on: Ubuntu 18.04, TeXlive 2019 (tlmgr)

Run

```
tlmgr info pzdr
```

You will find the package where `pzdr.tfm` is located. In this case, it is `zapfding`. Then what you have to do is run

```
tlmgr install zapfding
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, on TeXLive 2017 it was:

```
sudo tlmgr install palatino
```

The following might work as well:

```
sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

Comment: The correct spelling is TeXLive or simply `texlive` .

Comment: @evaristegd corrected :)